# android layout design issue

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to design a page and i am facing **three issues.**

The **first issue** is to design as in the following figure
[image]

Here the burger image(from an url) at the top must be with equal margin space along with rounded image placed over it with a text randomly changing over it. Below comes the OK and Cancel button with a grey background and an red icon exactly in the center. A small part of the red icon must be placed over the above image and 2 edit text and text views below it

The **second issue** is i have a button in my application bar when it is clicked the burger image view must be cleared and i have to show a map in it. In such a case the red icon must be remaining at its position with a small part over the map.

I am not sure about the imageView height and width but the map must be exactly replaced at the position of the image

The **third issue** is i want to design this page without a scroll view, the views must be within the screen, because if we are to use Frame Layout it is not accepting inside a Scroll view

So far i have tried the following

```
<LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/rrds_layout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:background="@color/burgerimg" >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rrds_round_points"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg" >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Free"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I don't know the way to add the red icon and buttons a little bit over the image

how to design this page.....

as [Vikram Bodicherla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619699/vikram-bodicherla) explained i have designed as follows

```
<FrameLayout>
     <ViewSwitcher>
          <TextView></TextView>
          <MapView></MapView>
     </ViewSwitcher>

       <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/rrds_merge_layout2"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom">

              <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:id="@+id/merge_bg_img"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/title_bg" 
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

              <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/merge_view_pro_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="OK"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/merge_center_img"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

              <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:id="@+id/merge_center_img"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/red_icon" />

               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/merge_view_cash_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="@string/mrg_cash"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/merge_center_img"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
         </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

But still the same problem exists......

Comment: 1. use transparent border for your image. 2. use relativeview to design you red icon bar. 3. use your parent as relative view.

Comment: @CasperOne - 2 of them are able to understand and one has given me a 60% of the solution and i am trying on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design the top part and the bottom part separately.

In the top part, have a FrameLayout/ViewSwitcher which swaps between a MapView and an ImageView. As for the rounded image, create an image which has a white round in the middle, leaving everything else transparent. Set this as the background to a TextView and write your text.

The design of the second part will be fairly simple.

Let me know if you need code for specific problems.

Comment: Thanks Vikram but no use... i have added my xml, any suggestions ?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand?!

Comment: as you have explained i tried out with a FrameLayout and View Switcher but still the bottom part(red icon with text both sides) lies over the image/map. I have added the new layout design in my question mentioning with ur name...